# Including validation method in another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a validation method that has to verify values assigned in another method, how can i get it to recognise those values before validation? the pay_must_be_same_to_amount method needs some values from the create_items_from_readings method

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :approved_by, :due_date, :invoice_date, :reading_ids, :terms, :customer_id, :customer, :status, :reference_no, :payment_method, :amount, :payment_date

  has_many :invoice_items, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :customer, :inverse_of => :invoices

  validate :pay_must_be_same_to_amount

  def create_item_from_readings
    item = invoice_items.new
    item.rate = customer.unit_cost

    readings_in_this_period = customer.unbilled_readings.where('date_of_reading <= ?',  invoice_date).order(:date_of_reading)
    return nil if readings_in_this_period.empty?

    self.reading_ids = readings_in_this_period.collect(&:id).join(',')

    total_units = 0
    readings_in_this_period.each do |reading|
      total_units = total_units + reading.units_used1 + reading.units_used2 + reading.units_used3
    end

    item.amount = total_units * customer.unit_cost * customer.ct_ratio
    item.tax_amount = (item.amount * Settings.vat) if customer.pays_vat

    invoice_from_reading = readings_in_this_period.first.previous_reading
    invoice_from_reading ||= readings_in_this_period.first
    invoice_to_reading = readings_in_this_period.last


  #Select Item description based on Phase type
    if customer.phase_type == 'Single Phase'
      item.description = "Electricity used from #{invoice_from_reading.date_of_reading.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} with readings #{invoice_from_reading.reading1} to #{invoice_to_reading.date_of_reading.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} with   reading #{invoice_to_reading.reading1} - #{total_units.to_i} total units"
    else
      item.description = "Electricity used from #{invoice_from_reading.date_of_reading.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} with readings, R1: #{invoice_from_reading.reading1}, R2: #{invoice_from_reading.reading2}, R3: #{invoice_from_reading.reading3} to #{invoice_to_reading.date_of_reading.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} with  readings, R1: #{invoice_to_reading.reading1}, R2:#{invoice_to_reading.reading2}, R3: # {invoice_to_reading.reading3}- #{total_units.to_i} total units"
    end
  end 
end
```

and the validation method is below, it needs to compare the item.amount above to the amount in the class Invoice

```
 def pay_must_be_same_to_amount
  if item.amount < self.amount && item.amount != self.amount
    self.errors.add :amount, 'The payment amount should be equal to amount on invoice' 
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A few comments: `create_item_from_readings` is way too complicated. I can't tell what it's supposed to do, but if you run it, I believe it will return a string (one of the two from the last `if` statement).

If all you need to do is compare `item.amount` to the invoice `amount` attribute, that's simple. You can use your validation method almost as you've written it, plus a few other methods as needed.

```
def item_amount
  total_units * customer.unit_cost * customer.ct_ratio
end

def total_units
  readings_in_this_period.inject(0) {|total,r| total + r.units_used1 + r.units_used2 + r.units_used3 }
end

def pay_must_be_same_to_amount
  if item_amount != amount
    errors.add :amount, 'The payment amount should be equal to amount on invoice'
  end
end
```

The code for both of those supplementary methods is simply modified code from your longer method.

A good rule of practice is that if a method is longer than one line, and you can't tell what it's for by glancing at it, it's too long (this isn't *always* true, but it's worth considering for complicated methods).

Comment: I have added some associations to illustrate what create_items_from_readings does, however, it is trying to populate invoice_items and invoice attributes. With regards to your methods item_amount and total_units, do i add into the method create_items_from_readings because if they are outside the values will be nil

Comment: Does it work? As far as I can tell, you are instantiating a new InvoiceItem but it's not being saved to the database.

Comment: Zach is right although it would be faster to use the db to calculate the total amount `customer.unbilled_readings.where('date_of_reading <= ?',  invoice_date).order(:date_of_reading).sum('units_used1 + units_used2 + units_used3')`

Comment: @ZachKemp if the method item_amount is outside the method create_items_from_readings it gives an error, undefined local variable or method total_units

Comment: Are you adding all of these methods to the `Invoice` class?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you mean. They should all be outside the `create_items_from_readings` method. As long as you have an `amount` attribute and relations for `customer` and `readings_in_this_period`, these methods should work.

Comment: @ZachKemp I got the solution by adding such the method below 'def pay_must_be_same_to_amount
     sum = 0
     self.invoice_items.each do |invoice_item|
      sum = sum + invoice_item.amount
    end
    if sum != self.amount
      self.errors.add :amount, 'The payment amount should be equal to amount on invoice' 
    end
  end'

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the question is

```
def pay_must_be_same_to_amount
 sum = 0
 self.invoice_items.each do |invoice_item|
  sum = sum + invoice_item.amount
end
 if sum != self.amount
  self.errors.add :amount, 'The payment amount should be equal to amount on invoice' 
 end
end
```